Does "iugiter" have any descendants in English?
Does the Latin term iugiter (or jugiter) have any descendants in English, even remote ones? It is morphologically similar to judge, but the two don't seem to have any etymological relationship.

There's an archaic cognate eche "eternal", but that's a descendant of the same PIE phrase, not a descendant of the Latin word itself.

As far as I can tell, this iugis (iugiter is the adverbial form) has no descendents in English. The closest we get in contemporary English is hygiene, from the Greek ὑγιής, which is cognate to it.
Middle English also preserved eche (from Old English ēċe), but it isn't used today.
Note, this is a very distinct word from both iugum (from iugi, "I joined"), which gives us words like conjugal, and also from judge, which comes from the Latin iudex, iudicis.

Hygiene is a great find! Thank you
